# Restoring a backup with rsync

Tags: rsync, kubuntu, restore

I'm getting back into Linux and am running Kubuntu 21.10, and I want to make a proper full backup of the system now that I've configured it how I like. This is the command I used to create a backup on a separate drive:

```
sudo rsync -aAXv / --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/media/*","/lost+found"} "/media/backuppath/"
```

This is what my partitions look like for the drive I want to back up:

```
/dev/sda1      fat32    /boot/efi   (primary)
/dev/sda2      extended
/dev/sda5      ext4     /
```

I am new to rsync, so it would be helpful to know if this backup command will take care of everything to restore an exact system backup: system settings, installed programs, etc. More importantly, what do I need to run to restore this if the time ever comes?

Comment: Many of us just back up data, list of apps & do a new install. New install is often quicker than restore as UUIDs may change if restoring to new partitions. So lots of settings to update. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545655/backup-your-home-directory-with-rsync-and-skip-useless-folders & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/40992/what-files-and-directories-can-be-excluded-from-a-backup-of-the-home-directory/40997#40997

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the most important, your last question.

What you need to run in order to restore your backup will depend… on the system you will have booted on…
Because in the worst case, (the case in which your full backup is actually useful) the system you backed up is just broken.

Since you get another disk, what about having it bootable so that, in the extreme worst case, you could start your system from it and restore the other disk.
The other immediate advantage is that you will avoid restoring a running system... which **always** leads to unpredictable results.

In this context, you'll then obviously want to avoid backuping the fstab and your bootloader configuration file as well as the bootloader itself. => Add their paths to the exclude list.

You will also want the --del feature of rsync.

You will also want to backup (and restore) with the strict minimum number of processes running. (I always throw my full rsync backups under console in single user mode.)

You will also prefer mounting your targets on /mnt subdirs and prefer rsyncing to /mnt/whatever than to /media/whatever.

My system gets 4 partitions root, boot, var and home. As an example of what I run :

```
if mount -L "${DEST_SYS}_ROOT"
    then
    if mount -L "${DEST_SYS}_VAR" "/mnt/${DEST_SYS}_ROOT/var"
        then
        if mount -L "${DEST_SYS}_BOOT" "/mnt/${DEST_SYS}_ROOT/boot"
           then 
               if mount -L "${DEST_SYS}_HOME" "/mnt/${DEST_SYS}_ROOT/home"
                   then
                   rsync -aXH --info=progress2 --del --exclude={"/boot/boot.${BOOT_EXCL}","/boot/map.${BOOT_EXCL}","/dev/*","/media/*","/mnt/*","/proc/*","/root/MySys/Conf/fstab","/root/MySys/Conf/lilo.conf","/root/MySys/Conf/issue","/run/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","lost+found"} / "/mnt/${DEST_SYS}_ROOT"
```

And then, coming back to where I started from, what command do you launch for restoring your backup ? The exact same one, launched from the backup system.

---

Nota : Of course, if your system went so badly broken that the fstab or the bootloader were corrupted, you might need to fix them manually.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! So I see you have some variables in there, I tried to echo the ${DEST_SYS}  ${BOOT_EXCL} ,and  but nothing returned. How are you setting that?

Comment: @tommythecat42 : These are variables local to the script. My working systems FS are labeled WRK_VAR, WRK_ROOT etc... while my backup FS are labeled BCK_VAR, BCK_ROOT etc… I get a third system labeled similarily. The variable $DEST_SYS will be set at the beginning of the script to equal the prefix "WRK_", "BCK_" or the third one depending on my choice for the destination of the backup. $BOOT_EXCL is also set at the beginning of the script to the suffix of the bootloader (/boot/boot.0800 or 0810 or else depending on the disk device used)